# Can't force element to the top with Z Index

Tags: css

I'm hoping someone can help me with a CSS question that I've spent the better part of a night trying to figure out. I'll be extremely grateful if any CSS gurus can help me out.

On our website www.anchoring.com we've implemented a third party search app. Unfortunately the instant search is appearing below our menu bar. I've tried using a z index of 999999 and it still appears below the menu bar. See our website and the image below: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jy4O.jpg)

The nav-container class contains a z index property. However, even if I set the z index to a higher number than that in the Instant Search it still appears below the container. If I remove the z-index from the menu bar the instant search results come to the top (but it messes with other things).

From my research, if the elements were nested in one another this behaviour could occur, but from what I can tell, they are not nested within one another.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is behaving in this way and/or how to potentially correct it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  A great way to do this is jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

you can get the results your needing by setting the z-index of .nav-container from 4 to 1

`.nav-container {
    z-index: 1;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :)

```css
.search{
position:relative;
z-index:100000; /* The z-index of search div should be more than the nav menu */
top:0;
right:0;
width:/* Your value here */;
height:/* Your value here */;
}
```